# How to add glyphicon in list style part in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I do not know how to add a glyphicon in a list style part, this is my code :

```
              <li>
                <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, do %>
                    <span class="glyphicon-glyphicon-user"></span> Signout
                <% end %>
              </li>
```

And I get these errors:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block destroy_user_session_path, do @output_buffer.safe_append=' ^

syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^

Comment: Pease tell us what is the problem with the existing code, and post the error if any.

Comment: _navigation.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block destroy_user_session_path, do @output_buffer.safe_append=' ^ 

_navigation.html.erb:31: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^

These are the errors I get when I type the code above

Comment: please add that to the question body (you can edit your question with the "edit" button below its body).

Answer (score 2):

The basic form of a glyph link in rails looks like this:

```
 <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i> Dashboard
<% end %>
```

Comment: But we are not using button, we just want the glyphicon beside the signout navigation, and it is inside the list item

Comment: check now please and let me know

Comment: Yeah I did like you told me but still I got the errors, please see  my edited question and errors

Comment: don't add glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon-user instead add glyphicon glyphicon-user

Comment: you are adding glyphicon-glyphicon-user two times which is not valid

Comment: The answer still contains the same invalid Ruby code as the question, namely the comma before the `do`. This is the reason for the Syntax error.